# How to access try catch error in Javascript through api request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

My nodejs api sends

```
res.status(401).json({ info: 'task cannot be done' })
```

as an error and I try to catch it on the client side via

```
try {
      const resp = await axios.get('https://localhost:3000/getinfo')
      console.log('resp!!!', resp)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error' , error )
    }
```

Although on my network tab I can see the message coming in JSON format I am not sure how to extract data from error.

How can I access `info` which is sent from the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With axios you can handler the error

```
 const resp = await axios.get('https://localhost:3000/getinfo').catch(err=> 'Do whatever you want with the error');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `error.response` to get the actual error received from the server on the client

```
console.log(error.response);
```

Comment: .response is undefined obviously.

Comment: No, @Hypothesis, its not. Your error object contains a response field, if your server responded with a 4xx/5xx error. Usually, this is the error we're most familiar with and is most straightforward to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these :

1.

```
     catch(error){
            const { details } = error;
            const message = details.map(i => i.message).join(',');
            return res.status(400).json({ error: {message:message} })
}
```

2. ```
    catch(err){
           let {message} = err;
           return res.status(400).json(
              {
                error: {
                     message: message,
                }
           });
     }
   ```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: This does not seem be answering the question.

Comment: @Hypothesiswhy not. I am sending here the extracted message . Nothing to do on the browser now.